# Why can't I preview Latex in editing the answers?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Here's my problem.

When I am editing someone's questions, I can preview the Latex with no problem.
[image]

But when I am editing someone's answers, I can't preview the Latex.
[image]

**I am living in China mainland and my colleague has the same problem, he couldn't preview the Latex in the answers too.**

Comment: yo, can you plz consider cropping the images to make them smaller in the future or use a format that uses less memory. some of us still use windows 97 here...

Comment: I think this is just your computer being slow, not a bug. occasionally happens to me too, as i pointed out, i am using an antique.

Comment: @Lost1 So basically I just have to wait? But sir, I have been waiting for 30 minutes and still nothing happen. Maybe it's because I am living in China mainland? My colleague has the same problem, he couldn't preview the Latex in the answers too.

Comment: hmm, then you need someone more qualified to answer this.

Comment: It seems that some people have experienced problem when using MathJax in China before: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/latex-is-not-properly-displayed and http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/accessing-mathjax-cdn-from-china (Maybe you will have more luck to [find a post](http://www.google.com/search?q=china+mathjax+blocked) having some reasonable suggestion how to solve this, I did not find anything immediate.)

Comment: On the other hand, as you only have problems when editing posts (and not when viewing them), it might be an entirely different problem.

Comment: MathJax rendering should all take place locally, so I don't think your location (or GFW) would be causing this.  Have you tried checking for updates to your browser / OS?

Comment: @AlexanderGruberI think it's GFW's problem, cause when I am using VPN I have no problem previewing Latex in answers

Answer (score 1):

This has already happened with me, follow these steps:

1. Check your list of add-ons, maybe there is some which is blocking mathjava (for instance Ghostscript, adblock,...).
2. Maybe you are using a proxy, maybe you have to disable it.
3. Go to preferences and check your cookies police.
4. click in the left of the address bar, there is a botton where has the site information, maybe you have to unblock the page.
5. If anything above worked, change your browser, there are a lot of them (Firefox, Opera, Chrome, among others).